# Pandas DataFrame with Function: Columns Varying

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Given the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d=pd.DataFrame({' Label':['a','a','b','b'],'Count1':[10,20,30,40],'Count2':[20,45,10,35],
                'Count3':[40,30,np.nan,22],'Nobs1':[30,30,70,70],'Nobs2':[65,65,45,45],
                'Nobs3':[70,70,22,32]})
d

    Label   Count1  Count2  Count3  Nobs1   Nobs2   Nobs3
0   a           10      20    40.0     30      65      70
1   a           20      45    30.0     30      65      70
2   b           30      10     NaN     70      45      22
3   b           40      35    22.0     70      45      32
```

I would like to apply the [z test for proportions](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html#statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest) on each combination of column groups (1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3) per row. By column group, I mean, for example, "Count1" and "Nobs1".

For example, one such test would be:

```
count = np.array([10, 20]) #from first row of Count1 and Count2, respectively
nobs = np.array([30, 65]) #from first row of Nobs1 and Nobs2, respectively
pv = proportions_ztest(count=count,nobs=nobs,value=0,alternative='two-sided')[1] #this returns just the p-value, which is of interest
pv
0.80265091465415639
```

I would want the result (pv) to go into a new column (first row) called "p_1_2" or something logical that corresponds to its respective columns.

In summary, here are the challenges I'm facing:

1. How to apply this per row.
2. ...for each paired combination, mentioned above.
3. ...where the column names and number of pairs of "Count" and "Nobs" columns may vary (assuming that there will always be a "Nobs" column for each "Count" column).

Related to 3: For example, I might have a column called "18-24" and another called "18-24_Nobs".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To 1) and 2) for one test, additional tests can be coded similar or within an additonal loop

```
for i,row in d.iterrows():
    d.loc[i,'test'] = proportions_ztest(count=row['Count1':'Count2'].values,
                                        nobs=row['Nobs1':'Nobs2'].values,
                                        value=0,alternative='two-sided')[1]
```

for 3) it should be possible the handle these case with pure python inside the loop

Comment: What if I need row['Count1' and 'Count3'].values?

Comment: A this point I am not so sure, what you are asking.
    'row['Count1':'Count2']'
gives you the columns from Count1 to Count2,
  'row[['Count1','Count2']]' will allow an to enumerate them in a list.

Comment: If I wanted just 'Count1' and 'Count 3' columns, I'd need to specify it differently, I believe, or it will assume I want all 3 instead of just 1 and 3. So I just need to know how to specify just 1 and 3 and not 2. I tried 'row['Count1':'Count3']' but it returned (obviously) data from 3 columns.

Comment: for i,row in d.iterrows():
    d.loc[i,'test'] = proportions_ztest(count=row[['Count1','Count3']].values,
                                        nobs=row[['Nobs1','Nobs3']].values,
                                        value=0,alternative='two-sided')[1]